# How to Migrate Data of a MongoDB Replicaset from one AWS account to another without downtime

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have a MongoDB 3 node replica set on AWS. Now I want to move or migrate it to another AWS account without any downtime. The configuration of servers would be same in the Second AWS account. I want it without using Atlas. Please suggest options to do this migration.

Is it possible to create the 4th replica of this replica set in the second AWS account(3 in 1st AWS account and 4th in second)? If it is possible then I can add more replicas to the second account and then phase out the replicas from 1st account.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add 4th node from different account in the existing replica set via VPC sharing if the 4th node is in different AWS Account. Reference: [VPC Sharing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/vpc-sharing-a-new-approach-to-multiple-accounts-and-vpc-management/)

Comment: Thanks Haridarshan

Comment: If two AWS accounts are of different companies/organisations then also is it possible to do this with VPC sharing? Or there is any other alternative method for this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use multiple AWS Accounts resources with VPC Sharing even if these AWS Accounts are of different companies/organisations. All you need to have is the required permissions.